# Need help on adding if-else-then using json schema validator using networknt when comparing objects in outer and inner schema

Tags: jsonschema, json-schema-validator

For example `declinfo` is mandatory only if `date` is mandatory. Similarly, I have to add validations in other inner objects.

The current schema:

```json
{
  "$schema":"http://json-schema.org/draft/2019-09/schema#",
  "type":"object",
  "description":"test",
  "title":"test",
  "properties":{
    "date":{
      "type":[
        "string",
        "null",
        "integer"
      ],
      "description":"Date",
      "format":"^[0-9]*$",
      "minLength":1,
      "maxLength":8
    },
    "declInfo":{
      "type":"array",
      "items":{
        "type":"object",
        "properties":{
          "number":{
            "type":"string",
            "format":"^[a-zA-Z0-9._\\- ]*$",
            "minLength":1,
            "maxLength":19
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`dependentRequired` to conditionally require certain properties](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/conditionals.html#dependentrequired). If you want to conditionally apply a schema [there is also `dependentSchema`](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/conditionals.html#dependentschemas).

For example you could add

```json
{
  "$schema":"http://json-schema.org/draft/2019-09/schema#",
  "type":"object",
  "description":"test",
  "title":"test",
  "properties":{
    "date":{
        ...
    },
    "declInfo":{
        ...
    }
  },
  "dependentRequired": {
    "date": ["declInfo"]
  }
}
```

full schema with your example: https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/s/3G68BVHh